# How to add views aware configuration options to a field formatter?

Tags: 8, views

There is a contrib field formatter module (bg_img_formatter) which has numerous field configuration options. One of these options is a text field which needs to allow for the same views field replacements as the "Rewrite Result:Override the output of this field with custom text" does. But as this is a "field" formatter and not a "Views field" formatter; the formatter class and specifically its viewElements() method is not "views aware".

Wondering what is required to make field formatter options views aware (when used within a view). Do I need to create a views field plugin? Can it add on to the existing field formatter or does it need to replicate all the code that is already here?

Comment: What do you mean by "views aware"? What features does such a class/method provide that you need?

Comment: "views field replacements as the "Rewrite Result:Override the output of this field with custom text" does"

Comment: So…you want your entity field formatter classes to have access to Views’ replacement tokens, when said formatters are used to render a field in the context of a Views row, is that if?

Comment: @Clive, Exactly. :)